# How can I to generate and serve sitemap.xml dynamically in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an application with a sitemap.xml. I need to modify it dynamically once a day. I know how to generate the content for it. But how can I actually replace(!) my current sitempa.xml with a new generated one, or rather its content?
If it was a rails app, I'd merely replace its content and it'll work, but for phoenix it's different.

My code for serving sitemap.xml is the standard one:

```
defmodule MyApp.Endpoint do
  # ................

  # Serve at "/" the static files from "priv/static" directory.
  #
  # You should set gzip to true if you are running phoenix.digest
  # when deploying your static files in production.
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt sitemap.xml)
```

Should I create a special route/action for "sitemap.xml" and serve it in a controller?

Answer (score 4):

I'd serve it from a controller/action and cache the value in memory for 24 hours.

```
# Router
get "/sitemap.xml", SitemapController, :index

# Controller
defmodule MyApp.SitemapController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    xml = ... # generate the sitemap / fetch from cache
    conn
    |> put_resp_header("content-type", "application/xml")
    |> send_resp(200, xml)
  end
end
```

To cache the value of `xml`, you can do this directly with an Agent or ETS Table or use a library like [cachex](https://github.com/whitfin/cachex) or [con_cache](https://github.com/sasa1977/con_cache).

Comment: Clean and simple. Would suggest using a file for thousands of pages.